# How do I determine my monster's hit points?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

I'm the traitor and I'm in control of a monster. The guide says this monster has a Speed, Might, and Sanity values of 3 each. How do I determine the monster's hit points, I.E. how much damage it can take until it's "defeated"? (This monster has a special property where it can be "defeated" instead of just getting stunned - see spoiler text.)

> This is scenario 48, Stacked Like Cordwood. Actually, the monster comes back stronger if "killed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, monsters don't get defeated or take damage; they're just stunned and lose their special negative effects and next turn. See spoiler text below for detail on this specific haunt:

> The Trator's Tome states "If Crimson Jack is defeated, he is temporarily removed from the house **instead of being stunned or taking damage**". The bolded part is what I missed when playing - I should have reset Jack's location and added to his stats when he was stunned.

Answer (score 2):

Monsters (like explorers) don't have hit points. If a scenario says that a monster can be killed instead of just being stunned, then that scenario should also say how it can be killed. It may just say that if it's defeated, then it is killed instead of stunned, or if it's defeated with a specific item, etc. You may have to be more specific in your question about which scenario you are playing, but just double check that scenario's rules; there are no general game rules to cover this.